# json loop php with array without id

Tags: php, arrays

I have this json array without id and variable email number:

Array contains multiple email separated by a comma:

```
[{"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"processed","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"FDl9L7nP4zJXgLYUGhqqoA==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"deferred","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"jbtTInm9Pej80gzRXRg9Pg==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","response":"400 try again later","attempt":"5"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"delivered","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"XUBvHRS8T0eD_Eea8IECDA==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","response":"250 OK"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"open","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"Wp2888u5ZaJX7Pd-_DbFpA==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","useragent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)","ip":"255.255.255.255"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"click","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"7iXIm9S5SAuhRmoy4QIZZg==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","useragent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)","ip":"255.255.255.255","url":"http://www.sendgrid.com/"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"bounce","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"3HJSeIIA2FzBjQxXvlf2hQ==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","reason":"500 unknown recipient","status":"5.0.0"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"dropped","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"8acL8P-wxlb0CJoxBEjYuQ==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","reason":"Bounced Address","status":"5.0.0"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"spamreport","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"cgn6ggkYz1S7XT5D5nRo9w==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"unsubscribe","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"suFV8ITF-9ND3j1SrlW-fA==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0"},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"group_unsubscribe","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"KljxrqIWTvF0mEshFKnw1Q==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","useragent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)","ip":"255.255.255.255","url":"http://www.sendgrid.com/","asm_group_id":10},
 {"email":"example@test.com","timestamp":1516820089,"smtp-id":"\u003c14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469@ismtpd-555\u003e","event":"group_resubscribe","category":"cat facts","sg_event_id":"F7oTvsqxOIQyRWyLJeXIjA==","sg_message_id":"14c5d75ce93.dfd.64b469.filter0001.16648.5515E0B88.0","useragent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.1; Windows XP; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)","ip":"255.255.255.255","url":"http://www.sendgrid.com/","asm_group_id":10}]
```

And i need to create a while/loop for getting separate email data, i have also tried with

```
$obj = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );
foreach ($obj as $value) {    
   $value->email;
}
```

but it return always and only the first or last value

Comment: How are you trying to output or store this list of emails?

Comment: It is a webhooks of sendgrid =)

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/index.html

Comment: Did you check if `$obj` has the expected content? I just checked the code without getting the data from input and it works.

Comment: Really, code for insert in mysql with pdo is incorrect for while, i have fixed and my code work =)

Comment: All of the email addresses in `email` are `example@test.com` so how do you know it's the first or last one???

Comment: What do you mean by "separate email data"? And what do you mean by "it return"? `$value->email;` doesn't actually return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you if you know your array keys, and it eliminates the double loop.

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents( 'php://input' ), true);
foreach($array as $innerArray){
    $emails[] = $innerArray['email'];
    //or do whatever you want with each email as $innerArray['email'], repeat for each key.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try like this:

```
$obj = json_decode( file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );
foreach ($obj as $item) {
   $props = get_object_vars($item);
   foreach ($props as $key => $value) {
       /*do what you like with $key and $value */
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but why not just use the true option in json_decode and get an array > an object to start with?

Comment: you'd still have to do 2 loops, but you're right, i just assumed he wanted objects from his code

Comment: Oh wow. Just reread the question - I thought he only wanted the email addresses. Would probably be better to have keys too.